# How to power a Real Time Clock with a 12V vehicle battery?

Tags: battery-operated, rtc

I have a real time clock that requires 2.5V to 3.6V, 35 microamps. I have a vehicle battery at a nominal 12V that could actually range from 10V to 15V for the sake of this question. What kind of circuit would I use to power the RTC? I'd like to maximize the efficiency so as to not put any more drain on the battery than necessary, and minimize parts count/cost.

Is a voltage regulator (maybe some sort of high efficiency one) the answer? Or can something simpler be done involving a voltage divider or zener diode or something?

Comment: If you look for a regulator, keep in mind that many need a minimal load

Comment: An alternative could be to just use a lithium coin cell (CR2032 for example) to power that RTC. That has the advantage that if the 12 V is disconnected the clock will keep the correct time.

Comment: If this is a lead-acid battery then the self discharge current of the battery will be far more than the 35uA of the RTC. Expect the battery to loose 5% capacity per month for a good battery at room temperature. BTW 35uA sounds a lot for a RTC, most are well below 1uA.

Comment: At 35 microamps a simple linear regulator will do fine. Because of what Steve said it's probably not worth worrying about efficiency *at all*. (Even if the battery didn't self-discharge, how much would you care about having 2500 years of battery life instead of only 600 years?)

Comment: What is the application here? Are you trying to put this RTC in a vehicular app using the hot battery bus as your backup source?

Answer (score 1):

Connect a 180K resistor and a 3V zener (in reverse) in series (with the zener connected to ground). Place a 0.1 uF electrolytic capacitor across the diode and draw your output from there.

Answer (score -5):

I would simply use a linear regulator like LM317 (not sure) but only if I can't use a simple coin cell.

Comment: The LM317 is a floating part, so it's no bueno -- you need to draw 10mA from its output just to get it to regulate!